Communication Channel under Doppler effect
Suppose I have a scheme of a radar station A transmits a signal to sense a car B moving with velocity $v$ and located at a distance $R$. At the same time node B also sends another signal to node A, under frequency selective fading channel. Denoting signal from A is $\mathbf{x}_A$, the signal from B is $\mathbf{x}_B$, both at discrete time. Approximately, the total received signal of $A$ at discrete time is
$\mathbf{y}_A [n] = \mathbf{x}_A[n - \tau]e^{j 2 \pi n f_D} + (\mathbf{h}_{BA} \ast \mathbf{x}_B)[n],$
where $\tau$ and $f_D$ are the time delay and Doppler shift due to target B, and $\mathbf{h}_{BA}$ is the channel taps between the channel from B to A.
I want to ask whether this assumption of channel modeling is correct. I am confused at the channel tap $\mathbf{h}_{BA}$ whether it can capture the Doppler effect or not because the target B is moving.
I appreciate all of your help.

A $\mathbf h$ that gets convolved with the transmitted signal cannot  include the Doppler shift; for convolution to be sufficient to  model the channel, the channel needs to be LTI (Linearly, Time Invariant), and Doppler shift violates the "TI" part of LTI.
So, you need multiply $\mathbf x_B$ with a complex sinusoid to represent its Doppler, too.

I hope I meant the same as you do, but just phrased it confusingly. Moved the "Linearly, Time Invariant" as explanation to LTI, so that it's clear only the time invariance is lost, not the linearity.

my upvote still stands.
